# Why doesn't build_runner generate files when serializing JSON in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, build-runner

I'm just trying to generate my files with the same command i stored like 3 months ago (i'm not very good with backend and devops) and now it doesn't generate the files anymore. 
It tells me to use the delete command which i don't remember but even using that one my files still won't be generated. 
This is what my log looks like, and below you can find the code for a simple class.

One of my guesses would be this has something to do with me changing my github account, since there's the permission issue mentioned.

Im using vs code in windows 10.

log file:

```
E:\1 Work\flutter_pilot> flutter pub run build_runner build
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 336ms

[WARNING] Deleted previous snapshot due to missing asset graph.
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot......
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot... completed, took 12.5s

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 787ms

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Found 13 declared outputs which already exist on disk. This is likely because the`.dart_tool/build` folder was deleted, or you are submitting generated files to your source repository.
[SEVERE] Conflicting outputs were detected and the build is unable to prompt for permission to remove them. These outputs must be removed manually or the build can be run with `--delete-conflicting-outputs`. The outputs are: lib/models/advisory-service-item.g.dart
lib/models/advisory-service.g.dart
lib/models/auth.g.dart
lib/models/contract.g.dart
lib/models/contributor.g.dart
lib/models/exact-cost-values.g.dart
lib/models/exact-cost.g.dart
lib/models/expert.g.dart
lib/models/paginator-info.g.dart
lib/models/person.g.dart
lib/models/project.g.dart
lib/models/system-country.g.dart
lib/models/user.g.dart
pub failed (78)
```

class file:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'organisation.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Organisation {
  final String name;
  Organisation({this.name});

  factory Organisation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OrganisationFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$OrganisationToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

changing the part and class to the same name of the file fixed the issue with me

Answer (score 124):

I had a similar issue, but I am using Android Studio IDE and I have done the following step:

**File => Invalidate caches / Restart**

Run following command:

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

About **--delete-conflicting-outputs**

Assume conflicting outputs in the users package are from previous builds, and skip the user prompt that would usually be provided.

[Reference](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner)

Comment: `flutter pub run` is deprecated; Use `dart run` instead.

`dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Answer (score 21):

**Just run this:**

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple

Comment: Yes @AlimovShohrukh

Answer (score 20):

If you read the error message carefully, you'll see that it's asking you to try adding `--delete-conflicting-outputs` at the end of your command. So you should try `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`.

Comment: As i already stated (mayhaps in a more broken english, since it's not my native language) i already tried that, but the files just get deleted and nothing is generated.

Comment: I see. Tho it seems the command stopped at user.g.dart? Have you checked on that file? I actually experience this error sometimes, and realize I just have a typo somewhere or a missing part 'something.g.dart' code

Comment: User is the last file in the list. Checked it it's just a name and an id get and set nothing wrong there.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being able to help you identify the problem. But based on my past experiences having that same error, it's usually a typo, some wrong code, or missing part 'file.g.dart' code. However, if you're willing to share your code with me, I can spend a bit of time to help you find where the problem is.

Comment: I Think this is a bug of build_runner delete all files related build_runner and restart the code editor , it will work

Comment: @Bawantha you mean remove the package and its generated files and have flutter update the packages again?

Comment: @morgred no need to remove package just delete files generated from build_runner ans start the process again

Answer (score 11):

In my case adding `part 'file_name.g.dart';` to the top of the file helped.

file_name.dart:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'file_name.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class YourClass {

    factory YourClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$YourClassFromJson(json);

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$YourClassToJson(this);

    // ... your class code
}
```

Comment: I needed this for the `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` to pick up the file and great the `.g.dart` file.

Comment: Wow, I had a typo in file_name, thanks for this answer

Comment: Adding the `part` line (even though VSCode will throw error just because it isn't generated yet) works for me...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. Solved by using the below command

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the main reason this happens to most of us, is the possibility that when you ran this command before, you added the generated `g.dart` file into your source control. this in turn prevents the `build_runner` from regenerating the previously generated `g.dart` files, which it does, even if you only need the new `g.dart` file. now, I understand that this might be hard to follow, but consider this:

1. Let's say you have a `search_entry.dart` file.
2. You ran the command, and generated the `search_entry.g.dart` file
   successfully.
3. You then proceed to add the generated `search_entry.g.dart` file to
   your source control repository.
4. You make another file, let's say maybe `cached_data_entry.dart`.
5. When you run the command a second time to generate the
   `cached_data_entry.dart`, it will try and delete the
   `search_entry.g.dart` file to regenerate it along with the
   `cached_data_entry.dart` file.
6. Since the `search_entry.g.dart` is protected under the source control,
   the build runner won't be able to delete it, so, it throws this
   error.
7. Now, what you need to do to fix the current situation, is delete the
   previously all the previously generated `g.dart` files,
   (`search_entry.g.dart` in our example), then add it to the ignored
   files in `.gitignore` file in your source control. then run the
   command again, and hopefully, you it will succeed this time.
8. What you should do in the future, is ignore these files from your
   source control right after you generated them.

Now, finally, I hope I've made it as clear as it should be.

Comment: Since when does source control not allow editing or deleting files?

Comment: @vrnvorona I think the wording was not precise. In OP's example, since *search_entry.g.dart* is tracked into source control, a branch change or a merge will modify it, making build_runner detect an external change and consider the file as a conflicting output. This is described in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner#source-control).

Comment: Anyway, this answer does a good job explaining what a conflicting output is and why does it happen.

Answer (score 4):

Running "flutter pub upgrade" solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. At first I generated a **myFirstGeneratedFile.g.dart** file then I needed another object type to store then when I tried to generate the file using this command =>

> `flutter packages pub run build_runner clean`

I got the error message.

I fixed it by deleting the file that i created before => **myFirstGeneratedFile.g.dart**  then run the command again.

> Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

try something like this via terminal:

1. Delete previous generated files via command: find ./ -name '*.g.dart' -delete
2. then: flutter packages pub run build_runner watch —delete-conflicting-outputs

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with package dependency, executing this `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` will do the thing.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Delete `.dart_tool` folder and run `flutter pub get`. After this, run the build runner command

Answer (score 2):

In my case , I have declared a dart file named `Organisation.dart` instead of small letter `organisation.dart` , refracting this and running the build runner again worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I had forgotten to **import the mobx_codegen** package

Answer (score 2):

In my case the build_runner process was successful but the .g files weren't produced. I had to restart the IDE (vscode) before I start seeing the .g files.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you add  `hive_generator` to `dev_dependencies`
You can download Package from -
https://pub.dev/packages/hive_generator

You can read the official documentation - https://dart.dev/tools/build_runner

Comment: While this may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thank you for review my comment i well by carvel next tiem Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` deprecated. Use `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add built_value_generator to the `pubspec.yaml` to `dev_dependencies` section
https://pub.dev/packages/built_value_generator

You can read the official documentation - https://dart.dev/tools/build_runner

Answer (score 1):

Add this file in the root directory with `pubspec.yaml`

`build.yaml` file

Add the following lines

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      freezed:
        options:
          any_map: true
          explicit_to_json: true
```

Then run

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_runner-2.2.0/lib/src/build_script_generate/bootstrap.dart:76:40: Error: Method not found: 'NullThrownError'.
      final error = e[0] as Object? ?? NullThrownError();
```

---

In my case, just updating all packages to the latest version solved the problem for me.

```
dependencies:
  freezed: ^2.4.2
  freezed_annotation: ^2.4.1
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this `targets` bit goes into `build.yaml` and **NOT** `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
part 'organisation.g.dart';
```

it must have the same name of the file.